# Visitor Counter with PHP

Tags: php, random

I would like to use fake dynamic visitor counter with PHP. I know rand(), function, but at every time I refresh page random digit can be anything.

I want the number to be run 500-2000 so it won't increase beyond 2000 and neither decrease below 500 and not instant drop from 800-500 it should be increase +5 to -5.

How can I achieve that with PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php , see the second function signature

Comment: You can use sessions....Check if session var is set, if it is not, set it, with value rand(500,2000)... Then increase/decrease that session variable, randomly (+ or -), and you can even randomize incrementation, rand (0,5)... It will look realistic... Limit value with additional conditions...

Comment: Sinisake thank you for smart answer! That is what I was expecting ;)

Answer (score -1):

use function rand http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

int rand ( int $min , int $max )

If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and getrandmax(). If you want a random number between 5 and 15 (inclusive), for example, use rand(5, 15).